# Python str not callable error

Tags: python

I know I'm missing something simple here:

```
>>> mystring = "abcdefghijk"
>>> if mystring(len) > 9:
...     mySlice = mystring[:8]
```

I just want to slice "mystring" to 8 characters, why I'm getting this error:

> Runtime error : 'str' object is not
>   callable

Thanks!

Comment: Learn to look at the full traceback: `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.  Your `if` clause is two lines long.  The traceback says the error is in line 1, where, as others have pointed out, you have tried to call the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error in your syntax (you're trying to call "mystring").
This should work:

```
>>> mystring = "abcdefghijk"
>>> if len( mystring ) > 9:
...     mySlice = mystring[:8]
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `mystring(len)` to `len(mystring)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `len(mystring)` instead of `mystring(len)`.

You're either confusing it with a object-method-type call such as `mystring.len()` (which also won't work), have committed a slight typo, or are dyslexic :-)

I'm guessing it's the middle of those three.

Answer (score 1):

It goes len(string), and to call a function it would be string.func() anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Others pointed the error, but you can truncate it right away. No need to check for the length (if you don't want to add some ellipsis there or something):

```
foo = 'textual data'
print foo[:100]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error info contains the corresponding line number.